# where clause for datatable in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I'm trying to make simple datatable, It's completely okay with out the where clues but I need the where clue to work "$this->db->where('user.user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));". Please help me to fine out whats going wrong here.

```
class Dashboard_model extends CI_Model{
    var $table = "todo";
    var $select_column = array("todo_id", "todo.user_id", "login", "content");
    var $order_column = array(null, "login", "content");
    public function make_query(){
        $this->db->select($this->select_column);
        $this->db->join('user', $this->table.'.user_id = user.user_id');
        $this->db->where('user.user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        if (isset($_POST["search"]["value"])){
            $this->db->like("login", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
            $this->db->or_like("content", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
        }
        if (isset($_POST["order"])){
            $this->db->order_by($this->order_column[ $_POST['order']['0']['column'] ], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }else{
            $this->db->order_by("todo_id", "DESC");
        }
    }
    public  function make_datatables(){
        $this->make_query();
        if ($_POST["length"] != -1){
            $this->db->limit($_POST["length"], $_POST["start"]);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function get_filtered_data(){
        $this->make_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    public function get_all_data(){
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: No error msg there at all. The where condition is not working  as a result I'm getting all the rows from the "todo" tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause is not working because you have used OR like

```
$this->db->or_like(`"content", $_POST["search"]["value"]`);
```

This will make OR condition inside query.

Use group start and group end before and after like query.

example

```
        if (isset($_POST["search"]["value"])){
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->like("login", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
            $this->db->or_like("content", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
```

**EDIT**

Also check raw query by

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: $this->db->group_start(); &  $this->db->group_end(); work for me. Thank you very much.